# Performance of aspectj DeclareMixin

Tags: aspectj

I have some entity class which is intensively used in my application.
Since I can't change the class impl, I'd like to use aspectj DeclareMixin to mix some attribute into this class when constructor is invoked.

A quick questions is:

How much performance impact will DeclareMixin bring to object construction in such a case?

Thanks

Leon

Comment: And what information are we supposed to base our wild guesses on? I highly doubt you will receive a satisfactory answer - especially without providing vital information like the class to advise and what to advise it with. And even then any answer will be pure speculation. Bottom line: Just try it out and run performance tests.

Comment: I'd say, axactly 37.329 %. `;-)` Sorry, could not resist.